# Vertical Alignment Issue with Boostrap form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having issues getting items vertically aligned in a search form I'm working on.

I've tried enclosing everything in `<div class="form-row align-items-center">` but it's still not centering.

Basically I have:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="get">    
    <div class="panel panel-default">        
        <div id="searchheading" class="panel-heading search-collapse">
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body collapse in" id="search">
            <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    Label and select here
                </div>

              <div class="form-group col-md-5">

                Label and select here
              </div>


                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <input class="form-control" id="SearchString" name="SearchString" type="text" value="">
                </div>

                <input id="Search" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="ClearSearch">Clear</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've made a bootply here of the actual code: https://www.bootply.com/CxtLh1XGT5

I'm wanting the label and selects to all be centered with each other, but as you can see in the bootply, they are not.

Can someone with more CSS experience offer help as to what I need to do?  Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way to achieve this is by using using css flex.

```css
@media(min-width: 768px){
  .vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form class="form-inline" method="get">

  <div class="visible-xs-block" id="xs-check"></div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">

    <div id="searchheading" class="panel-heading search-collapse">

      <b data-toggle="collapse" href="#search" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="search">
                Search
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></i>

            </b>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body collapse in" id="search">
      <div class="form-row vertical-align">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="SelectedStatus">Status</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="SelectedStatus" name="SelectedStatus">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Open</option>
            <option value="1">Closed</option>
            <option value="2">All</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-5">

          <label for="SelectedBuildingList">Building</label>
          <select class="chosen form-control" id="SelectedBuildingList" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedBuildingList" style="width: 85%;">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">B1</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="2">B2</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="3">B3</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="4">B4</option>
          </select>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <input class="form-control" id="SearchString" name="SearchString" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <input id="Search" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="ClearSearch">Clear</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That does get them centered, but when I have that class added, and I shrink down the screen size, the form groups all remain in a row, and don't move to a horizontal alignment as they do without that class.

Comment: I modified my example to include a media query to match the col-md breakpoint.

Comment: You can achieve this using css vertical-align but it requires that you have comments in html to remove whitespace between your html elements. it's hacky and ugly, hence the recommendation of using flex.